# Handling a 403 in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I'd like to redirect a user to `/login` if they receive a 403 from my API. Here is what I have in my `/app/routes/application.js`:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import ApplicationRouteMixin from 'ember-simple-auth-auth0/mixins/application-route-mixin';

export default Ember.Route.extend(ApplicationRouteMixin, {
  actions: {
    error(error, transition) {
      if (error.status === '403') {
        this.replaceWith('login');
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

But this doesn't seem to work nicely with Ember Data, and when a 403 is returned, the exception is raised, but not handled by the router, any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override your Ember Data application adapter to catch 403s. Doing things there then allows you to handle things to trigger a redirect as desired:

```
// app/adapters/application.js

import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend({
  handleResponse(status, headers, payload, requestData) {
    if(status === 403) {
      // throw an error to be caught at the app level
      // or work with a service to handle things as desired
    }

    return this._super(status, headers, payload, requestData);
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you show me an example of this? I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: Sure, just updated. This should handle what you're after.